# Xpath is unable to find text

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="filterInfoContainer">
    <div class="result-header-right">
      <div class="show-soldout">
        <label for="soldout-switch">Display sold out products</label>
        <label class="switch xs">
          <input type="checkbox" name="soldout-switch" id="soldout-switch">
          <div class="switch-slider"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="sort-by">Sorted by:
        <select id="sortByDropdown">
          <option value="popularity">Popularity</option>
          <option value="price">Lowest price</option>
          <option value="discount">Highest discount</option>
          <option value="year">Latest release</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
      Showing 323 products
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>
```

**Xpath I tried**

```
.//*[@id='filterInfo']/div
.//*[@id='filterInfo']/div/text()
```

I want to get text **Showing 323 products** but my xpath does not return me. As this text has no particular **div** I am getting difficulty to get it.

**Selenium code I tried**

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='filterInfo']/div"));

 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='filterInfo']/div/text()"));
```

> Getting exception : Invalid Selector

Comment: Is there a possibility to move "Showing 323 products" into a <div> tag by doing a code change?

Comment: @Fey - No possibility for code change :(

Answer (score 1):

You can get **Showing 323 products** with `//div/text()`. 
Basically it will return the text that is not wrapped in tags. 
Please refer this [example](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/bdccfb2f58acf833fca3c75abce1d871).

So in your case:

`//div[@class='filterInfoContainer']/text()`

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/d06b22fb023db960d8fc619485759127

Answer (score 0):

Try using developer tools in Chrome to find the "filterInfo" component via xpath first, and see if that works.

Comment: if your component with the id "filterInfo" is inside a table for exaple, then maybe you have to write it like this: "table-id:filterInfo"

Answer (score 0):

In `Selenium` `XPath` expression should return `webelement` only while your second `XPath` intend to return text node. That's why you get `Invalid Selector` exception.

Also I see no `div` with `id="filterInfo"` in provided `HTML` sample. If you need to get `"Showing 323 products"`, try below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class="filterInfoContainer"]/div[1]")).getText();
```

*Considering updated `HTML` sample*, another approach for case when you need to get text excluding text of child elements:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("return document.evaluate('//div[@class=\"filterInfoContainer\"]/div/following-sibling::text()', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().textContent;");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just updated html code, Can you please update answer based on that.

Comment: Try updated answer and let me know if it doesn't work. You might need to use `trim()` to remove unnecessary spaces

Comment: `JavaScriptExecutor` doesn't return required value, return incorrect value, return nothing, exception?

Comment: It does not through any error or exception, but also does not return any text.

Comment: Does provided `HTML` sample looks exactly as real `HTML`? Maybe you removed some nodes? Also try to add some `sleep` time bore executing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138899/discussion-between-helping-hands-and-andersson).